# Freetronics LCD pins all used up

Tags: arduino, lcd

I am new to electronics and recently bought Freetronics Arduino experiment kit with the Freetronic LCD shield with keypad. I have installed the LCD shield and now I realize I no longer have any pins to plug in my existing wire to breadboard and LED. Is there anyway out?

Answer (score 3):

The FreeTronics LCD + Keypad Shield is documented to use only `D4-D9` for LCD control, ***any one of*** {`D2, D3, D10, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5`} for the backlight, and `A0` for the 4 buttons.

This should leave sufficient unused pins for your breadboard and LED needs.

Perhaps your concern is the physical connection of the shield to all the pins of the Arduino: That is how typical Arduino shields are designed. Some ship with "stackable" header pins, so another shield can be stacked atop or beneath this shield.

Of course, with a display shield, stacking another shield on top of it makes little sense. Hence they wouldn't provide stackable headers in this case.

So your way out is to use **any of the GPIO pins other than the ones listed** at the top of this answer, for your purposes. The shield doesn't use them, you can just tap them as needed.

For accessing those pins, you can either **solder wires** to the underside of the arduino, or use gripping **test probes** on individual pins, between the arduino and the shield, such as these probes below.

[image: Test probes] <sub>From [this eBay listing](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5-Colours-Single-Hook-Clip-Mini-Grabber-Test-Probe-for-SMD-IC-Multimeter-DIY-NEW-/290833605922?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item43b708a522)</sub>

Comment: That's the problem, they can't physically access the pins.

Comment: that's the problem I am facing too, and I am beginner.

Comment: I've shared what I use for this very situation... See edit to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the LCD shield description:

The buttons provide "left", "right", "up", "down", and "select" while using just one analog input. That leaves the other analog inputs free for you to use in your projects.

Hence there are pins still unused, but the LCD shield provides no stacked headers to put your wires in. Design mistake.

You could

- solder a header to the analog pins of your LCD shield.
- cut the unused LCD shield pins, so you can put wires in the underlying connector and still plug the LCD shield in.
- put a prototype shield with stackable headers inbeteween, and solder wires (or connectors) to that shield.

None of these solutions is very elegant. Blame the LCD shield design.

Comment: can I solder to the Prototyping area of arduino ?

Comment: That is possible, but it seems to be located at the wrong side, and it will be covered by the shield, so it might be impractical.

Answer (score 0):

That shield was not made with regards to expansion. A LCD is normally on the top, so it wasn't designed with stacking headers.

You will need a shield that allows you to pass through, like a stacking breadboard shield (Two sets of headers so you can use the breadboard and put another shield on top), or a breakout shield (Adafruit has one that has a prototype area, stacking headers, and screw terminals).

The other options are (in order of ease):

- **Wrapping a wire** around the headers on the lcd shield, before you plug it in.
- Using the kit's Male to Male jumper wires to connect from the Arduino to the breadboard, and then use some Male to Female wires to connect from the Arduino to the LCD Shield. (This prevents stacking, but you get to use both with minimal cost)
- **Cut the unused pins off the LCD Shield**. Stick plain wire (not the solderless jumper wire, it has hard plastic at the ends that can't bend) into the Arduino before you plug in the LCD Shield. Since the wire can bend at a 90° angle easily, it just bends out of the way.
- Soldering wires to the top side of the lcd shield's header pins.
- Replacing the lcd shield's headers with stacking headers.